# Why this dpkg error: ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' ...?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt, dpkg

I have some weird errors while trying to install  packages with software center or even when I try to upgrade packages with sudo apt-get install upgrade:

```
dpkg: error: file triggers record mentions illegal package name `libglib2.0-0' (for interest in file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules'): ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' with more than one installed instance
```

Previously I had error:

```
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
```

but I have just removed it with: `sudo rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`, I guess [this post](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/174320) describes this issue - I have followed it, but the last part `sudo apt-get install dpkg=1.16.0.3ubuntu5` did not work for me - no such package could be found. Probably it is because I am using ubuntu 12.04.

UPDATE:
adter trying to installcorrect version of dpkg 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 as suggested in the answer, I now get following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg=1.16.1.2ubuntu7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

By the way, this might be also helpful:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a 
dpkg: error: file triggers record mentions illegal package name `libglib2.0-0' (for interest in file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules'): ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' with more than one installed instance
```

which is actually telling the same thing.

UPDATE: content of (...) modules:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules$ ls
giomodule.cache      libgiognutls.so                 libgvfsdbus.so
libdconfsettings.so  libgiolibproxy.so
libgiognomeproxy.so  libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
```

UPDATE: /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File

```
$ sudo grep libglib /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: I have found [similar issue here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/how-to-fix-ambiguous-package-name-libglib2-0-0-problem) but it has not been solved

Answer (score 3):

> no such package could be found. Probably it is because I am using ubuntu 12.04.

The corresponding version for Ubuntu 12.04, as of this date, should be `1.16.1.2ubuntu7`.

> `ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable`

This is a [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/ia32-libs-multiarch/download) to the `ia32-libs-multiarch` page, where you can download the .deb file. Please use `dpkg -i filename.deb` to manually install it, and if successful, try apt-get again. If not, please update with dpkg error.

---

I installed ia32 on a test x86_64 system, and got the following for the contents of the triggers File and the contents of giomodule.cache. Please check to see how yours differ:

```
izx@myprecise:~$ grep libglib /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:i386

izx@myprecise:~$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules
giomodule.cache      libgiognutls.so                 libgvfsdbus.so
libdconfsettings.so  libgiolibproxy.so
libgiognomeproxy.so  libgioremote-volume-monitor.so

izx@myprecise:~$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/giomodule.cache 
libgiognutls.so: gio-tls-backend
libgioremote-volume-monitor.so: gio-native-volume-monitor,gio-volume-monitor
libgvfsdbus.so: gio-vfs,gio-volume-monitor
libgiolibproxy.so: gio-proxy-resolver
libdconfsettings.so: gsettings-backend
libgiognomeproxy.so: gio-proxy-resolver
```

Comment: thanks, +1 since now I get another error while trying to install it :) feel free to observe my update

Comment: I updated with a link to the deb, please try installing it, sometimes apt-get needs dpkg to give it a little help :)

Comment: thanks I tried this, unfortunately I still get error `$ sudo dpkg -i ia32-libs-multiarch_20090808ubuntu35_i386.deb `  
`dpkg: error: file triggers record mentions illegal package name `libglib2.0-0' (for interest in file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules'): ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' with more than one installed instance`

Comment: Can you update question with the content of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules`? If it's big, just the line containing `libglib2.0-0` and 2-3 lines before and after it will do.

Comment: done - Icannot see libglib2.0-0 there nor anything similar. There is one cache file that looks suspicious

Comment: Thanks, can you post output of `dpkg --list | grep libglib`?

Comment: Sure, but nothing useful, the same error:

`$ sudo dpkg --list | grep libglib
dpkg-query: error: file triggers record mentions illegal package name `libglib2.0-0' (for interest in file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules'): ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' with more than one installed instance`

Comment: Try `sudo grep libglib /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` and paste.

Comment: I added ia32 to my sample system and updated the answer with the "known-good" contents of various files. Please check and compare.

Comment: everything is the same, except of the order of entries in `giomodule.cache`, but entries are the same

Comment: And there are no extra or odd characters in the libglib entries in `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`?

Comment: nothing I have noticed, I have updated the question with the output

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issues.

I removed the line

```
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0
```

from `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`

Although being a bit of a novice, I'm not sure it was a good idea or not, but it at least removed the error so I could continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the method of the user user76204 worked for me but instead of just deleting `/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0` from the file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`
I had to delete all 3:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0                                         
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0                                                          
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0
```

I don't know if this going to cause problems in the future but I managed to pass the upgrade for now