# dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package `libglib2.0-0:i386'

Tags: dpkg

I had very similar issue which was described in this question - 
[Why this dpkg error: ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' ...?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134283/ambiguous-package-name-libglib2-0-0-with-more-than-one-installed-instance/134289). It didn't give me solution, but I have modified  `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and I have removed duplication of ligbglib2-0-0 or something like it. I've started to get a new error, which is almost exactly the same, but I can't see anything that's duplicated in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From a post I read on http://lists.debian.org/debian-dpkg/2012/06/msg00071.html
I could solve my problem by running:

```
 sed -n -e"s,/,\\\\\\\\/,g; s/:$(dpkg --print-architecture)$//p " \
       /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File \
 | while read line; do
      sudo sed -i -e"/^$line$/d" /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
 done
```