# dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/share/icons/hicolor' and package `hicolor-icon-theme'

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I can't install or remove any packages right now. Every aptitude or dpkg command fails with

```sh
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename
`/usr/share/icons/hicolor' and package `hicolor-icon-theme'
```

I tried the sed trick from [dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package `libglib2.0-0:i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134842/dpkg-error-duplicate-file-trigger-interest-for-filename-usr-lib-gio-modules/203056#203056), but that didn't work for me.

I'm running 12.10 with 3.2.0-32.

**Edit 1:**

```sh
ls -al /usr/share/icons/hicolor`
  total 92
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Jun 19 18:56 .
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 24 23:11 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 128x128
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 16x16
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 192x192
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 22x22
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 24x24
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 May  4  2011 256x256
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 32x32
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 36x36
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 48x48
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 64x64
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 72x72
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 96x96
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root  1252 Nov  3  2012 icon-theme.cache
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root 24671 Mar 22  2012 index.theme
  drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr  1  2009 scalable
```

**Edit 2:**

```sh
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor hicolor-icon-theme
  /usr/share/info install-info
  /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content wordpress
  /etc/init ureadahead
  /etc/init.d ureadahead
  /usr/man man-db
  /usr/share/man man-db
  /usr/local/man man-db
  /usr/local/share/man man-db
  /usr/X11R6/man man-db
  /opt/man man-db
  /etc/ufw/applications.d ufw
  /etc/lsb-release plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
  /usr/lib/mime/packages mime-support
  /etc/sgml sgml-base
  /usr/share/package-data-downloads update-notifier-common
  /usr/share/fonts fontconfig
  /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts fontconfig
  /usr/share/texmf/fonts fontconfig
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:amd64
  /etc/php5/conf.d libapache2-mod-php5
  /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/share/mime/packages shared-mime-info
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0:amd64
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor hicolor-icon-theme
```

Comment: Would you include a link to the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`? (Assuming the problem is related to this file.)

Comment: I have kind of replicated the error: **a)** I duplicated the `hicolor` line in `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`, **b)** I tried installing something that might update `hicolor` (`sudo apt-get install xpdf`), and **c)** the package gets downloaded but when the installation starts there's the error and on the last line: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`.

Comment: edwin: question updated with the contents of the file.

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software sources... > Other software tab > Is there any line related to "hicolor-icon-theme"?

Comment: The first and last lines of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` are duplicates, remove one. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice the first and last lines of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` are duplicates (both contain the same about `hicolor`). Try removing one of the lines (leaving the other!):

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
```

then save it. Then try installing/removing software again.

You might also want to run `sudo apt-get clean`, since `apt-get` might have cached the packages that failed to install.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with re-set the file-attributes by :

> chmod 755 /usr/share/icons/hicolor && chmod 755 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*

Then reboot your machine and check if this helped or if problems stay the same.

If problem stay the same then :

> apt-get install --reinstall dpkg*

then :

> dpkg --purge hicolor-icon-theme

after that install it again :

> dpkg -i hicolor-icon-theme

Yes, I know, this looks trivial, but often it is only a read-write-error of installed packages resp. a matter of file-attributes.

Comment: chmod didn't help. The `apt-get install --reinstall` command fails with the same dpkg error.

Comment: goto sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
":" Delete all occurrences and save the file, then run sudo apt-get update.

Comment: j0h — that worked. Can you make a real answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is presented a little solution for similiar situation (it comes from debian-list) :

http://useranswer.com/answer/dpkg-error-duplicate-file-trigger-interest-for-filename-usrlibgiomodules-and-package-libglib2-0-0i386/

Maybe this helps already ?

There this "duplicate - error" is solved by:

> sed -n -e"s,/,\\/,g; s/:$(dpkg --print-architecture)$//p "
>
> ```
>  /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
> ```
>
> | while read line; do
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i -e"/^$line$/d" /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
> ```
>
> done

Comment: That's the exact same technique I already stated didn't work. Please click the link in my question.

Comment: what output has ls -al /usr/share/icons/hicolor ?

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/ukueCurN

Comment: @PaulSchreiber Don't quite know, if this is a matter of file-attribute ?! try this: chmod 755 /usr/share/icons/hicolor and chmod 755 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/* ( after this reboot your machine and check if problems stay the same ) - otherwise this would then go deeper. If no success I will look at it tommorrow again. Now bed-time for me.